# Mac Store screen size

Tags: macos

I have a book app for the mac , the image sizes for each page are 1024x768. My problem is trying to figure out the display each page.

- Should I make it a full screen app - but then might get some horrible
  scaling on large monitors.
- I could leave it fixed at 1024*768 - this could also be frustrating on really large/small monitors

I've never done this before so have no idea where to start.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the book format the will be compatible with your app:

- If it will use images based books, the fullscreen mode is a bad idea (because of the scalling problem)
- If it's structured data books (epub, xml,...), the scalling won't be a problem!

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am using images so will avoid full screen. But if I use a fixed window size(1024*768) how do I know if it will look OK on really large/small monitors?

Comment: With images, the best thing to do would be to detect the screen resolution and the image size: so you can apply a "reasonable" scalling according to the screen resolution. 

You will only have to define a maximum tolerance for zooming (for example 120% max) to avoid horrible representation! So your app will automatically scale the image, but within an acceptable range.